# Use the attribute of a model in a scope

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have defined an attribute in my model and want to use it in a scope.

```
protected $appends = ['lowest_price'];

public function getLowestPriceAttribute()
{
    $lowest_price = NULL;
    foreach($this->shops as $shop) {
        if(is_null($lowest_price)) { 
            $lowest_price = (double)$shop->pivot->price;
        }

        if($lowest_price > (double)$shop->pivot->price) {
            $lowest_price = (double)$shop->pivot->price;
        }
    }
    return $lowest_price;
}
```

The lowest_price attribute I would like to use in a scope but it's always 'null':

```
public function scopeMaxPrice(Builder $query, $max_price): Builder {
    return $query->where('max_price', '>=', $this->lowest_price);
}
```

If I dd(); the getLowestPriceAttribute function in the scope it also returns 'null'. In my view I have access to the 'lowest_price' attribute.

Can the attribute be part of the query? If not, is there an elegant solution?

EDIT: The scope gets called in the Product controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $products = QueryBuilder::for(Product::class)
        ->allowedFilters(
            AllowedFilter::exact('type_id')->default('1'),
            AllowedFilter::scope('min_speed')->default(0),
            AllowedFilter::scope('min_range')-> default(0)
           # AllowedFilter::scope('max_price')-> default(999)
        )
        ->get();

    $types = DB::table('types')->pluck('name', 'id');
    return view('pages.home', compact('products', 'types'));
}
```

Note: I am using the Spatie querybuilder

Comment: how are you calling this?  new instances of the builder and potentially the model are being created so it wouldn't have any attributes as it is just being created to pass the call to the builder and for the builder to call the scope method

Comment: @lagbox all the code resides in the 'Product' model.

Comment: where are you calling this scope?

Comment: @lagbox the scope gets called in the index function of the productscontroller. Code has been added to the question.

Comment: the eloquent builder is referencing a new model instance so there are no attributes and no relationships because there are no keys to use to look up ... this is probably how you should look at scopes, they are not related to a particular instance of a model

Comment: @lagbox thanks for the explanation. Is there a way I am still able to use the lowest_price in the scope? As I understand it now, the attribute has to be stored in the database of it to be available in the scope. Is it possible to recalc the attribute everytime the model gets updated in the database? Or is there a better solution?